# Save_kable() doesn't work when save file as pdf format

Tags: r, pdf, kableextra

I met a problem recently. I want to use kableExtra package to translate some data into html and pdf formats.

But when I save data as pdf type, there gives me warning code:

```
library(kableExtra)
#########  2021-05-01 17:11:01
dt<-mtcars
#######
kbl(dt, caption = "<center>Table 1:mtcars</center>",escape = FALSE, booktabs = T) %>%
  #  kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "hover","condensed"),full_width = F,html_font = 7,font_size = 12)%>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "hover","condensed"),full_width = F,html_font = 7,font_size = 12)%>%
  kable_classic(full_width = F, html_font = "Cambria")%>%
  row_spec(0 ,  bold = F, extra_css = 'vertical-align: middle !important;')%>%
#  save_kable(file = "mtcars_05.01.html", self_contained = T)
  save_kable(file = "mtcars_05.01.pdf")

waring:
PhantomJS not found. You can install it with webshot::install_phantomjs(). If it is installed, please make sure the phantomjs executable can be found via the PATH variable.
save_kable could not create image with webshot package. Please check for any webshot messages
```

And I tried to solve it through its attention but it still doesn't work.

So I hope somebody give me some advice. Vary thankful.

###############  2021-05-02 12:10:45
I tried to install the  phantomjs by webshot::install_phantomjs(). There is still another warning code exist：

```
Note that HTML color may not be displayed on PDF properly.
Warning message:
In magick::image_write(img_rework, file, density = density) :
  Writing image with 0 frames
```

Comment: Well... is phantom.js installed and in the PATH??

Comment: Somebody here could help me ?

Comment: @dario ,yes I installed it but new  problem appeared.

Answer (score 2):

First save your table as HTML and then use webshot::webshot() to convert it to PDF.

```
save_kable(dt, file = "mtcars.html")
webshot("mtcars.html", "mtcars.pdf")
```